# Place title of subplot left of subplot row

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Is it possible to place the titles of subplots on the left hand side of the plots, when placed in a grid of x*2 subplots? The plots share the x-axis, and are placed two-by-two as they represent traffic counts for roads in both directions. The idea of the layout: [image]

With subplots placed as found [here](https://matplotlib.org/1.4.1/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html) :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Simple data to display in various forms
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x ** 2)

# row and column sharing
f, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex='col', sharey='row')
ax1.plot(x, y)
ax1.set_title('Sharing x per column, y per row')
ax2.scatter(x, y)
ax3.scatter(x, 2 * y ** 2 - 1, color='r')
ax4.plot(x, 2 * y ** 2 - 1, color='r')
```

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a direct way of doing this. I believe your best bet is with [`plt.text()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html).